# Get a location of application in open with list of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, jpeg

Today after system restore I found a suspicious application with name `%1` in open with a list of application that can open JPG images. So, I want to know where this application installed on my hard-drive. I tried searching in the registry but there were very many entries with `%1` in their name and soon found my self going nowhere. Windows search doesn't give any results for `%1`. So, is there any other better way to find application rather than going through the registry?

---

[image]

---

**EDITS**

I also tried running following command after setting `%1` application as the default application. But as evident from the following image, it didn't work.

[image]

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the program location as follows,

1. Set the program as the default program for the particular file type.
2. Open the `registry editor` and go to,

`HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.TheExtensionYouWantToModify\UserChoice`.

For example in my case,

`HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg\UserChoice`

3. Copy the value of ProgID
4. Now Search for Value of project ID till the key by the name of value is not found.
5. Ones required key is found then the path to the application can be found in subdirectories of that key.

For me, the app that I was searching was `%1` was actually due to corrupted keys of QuickTime.

Hope this helps.